# CSS height limit with higher priority than width restriction

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of bricks (block elements with fixed height) located on the lines like text words. I used CSS display:inline-block (or inline-table) for bicks. Each brick contains an arbitrary text from external source.

I want to set such CSS rules, that gives the fixed height of bricks and the minimum possible width by word wrap (within the limits of given height).

CSS:

```
/* my 'brick' rule*/
div{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5em;
  /*width: 10ex;*/
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
word word
</div>

<div>
word word word
</div>

<div>
word word word word
</div>

<div>
word a word longlongword word
</div>

<div>
word word
</div>

<div>
word the longwords longwords longlongword word
</div>

<div>
word word word
</div>

<div>
word word longlongword word
</div>

<div>
word word word word
</div>
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/1s5ff4bd/22/

the red brick is my problem, and the green shows what I want to get (but without using the manually inserted `<br>` tags).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the formatting blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: There is no direct way to get this behavior with inline-blocks. flexbox might be able to get you a little closer, but if you need this to break into multiple lines if necessary, that’s likely not going to work that well either.